# Java or Eclipse 'fails' on Whitespaces(?)

Tags: java, eclipse, whitespace

After many questions asked by other users this is my first one for which I was not able to find a fitting answer.

However, the problem sounds weird and actually is:
I have had more than one situation in which whitespaces were part of the problem and common solutions to be find on stackoverflow or elsewhere did not help me.

First I wanted to split a String on whitespaces. Should be something like

```
String[] str = input.split(" ")
```

But neither `(" ")` nor any regex like `("\\s+")` worked for me. Not really a problem at all. I just chose a different character to split on. :)

Now I'm trying to clean up a string by removing all whitespaces. Common solution to find is

```
String str = input.replaceAll(" ", "")
```

I tried to use the regex again and also `(" *", "")` to prevent exception if the string inludes no whitespaces. Again, none of these worked for me.

Now I'm asking myself whether this is a kinda weird problem on my Java/Eclipse plattform or if I'm doing something basically wrong. Technically I do not think so, because all code above works fine with any other character to split/clean on.

Hope to have made myself understood.

Regards Drebin

edit to make it clearer:
I'm caring just about the "replacing" right now.
My code does accept a combination of values and names separated by comma and series of these separated by semicolon, e.g.:

> 1,abc;2,def;3,ghi

this gets two time splitted, first on comma, then on semicolon. Works fine.

Now I want to clear such an input by removing all whitespaces to proceed as explained above. Therefore I use, as already explained, `String.replaceAll(" ", "")`, but it does NOT work. Instead, everything in the string after the FIRST whitespace, no matter where it is, gets removed and is lost. E.g. the String from above would change to

> 1,abc;

if there is whitespace after the first semicolon.

Hope this part of code works for you:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // some info output

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;

    System.out.println("\n wait for input ...");
    input = scan.next();

    if(input.equals("info"))
    {
        // special case for information
    }
    else if(input.equals("end"))
    {
        scan.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {   
        // here is the problem:
        String input2 = input.replaceAll(" ", "");

        System.out.println("DEBUG: "+input2);

        // further code for cleared Strings
    }
  } 
}
```

I really do not know how to make it even clearer now ...

Comment: (I like the name, officer Drebin :) ). Instead of `" *"`, I'd use `" +"`, because `*` matches 0 occurrences, and `+` matches 1 or more occurrences... But the absolute best would be `"\\s+"`

Comment: when you are trying to remove white spaces I think the easiest is to use trim() on string which removes whitespace characters from leading and ending. for all spaces this code works: ` input = input.replaceAll("\\s", ""); `

Comment: @kolboc only from the start and end of the strings... OP seems to need to do that in the middle too...

Comment: That sounds weird alright. What do you mean when you say they didn’t work, what result did you get? Any error messages?

Comment: Also, could you have an example of the input you use? The problem might lie around that...

Comment: In case of the split nothing happend and the array was empty.

Comment: Strange. Could you provide a larger block of code to see what is going on?

Comment: So both `input` and `str` have the whitespaces in it? (`input` will not be changed, be sure to use that in the code afterwards...)

Comment: yes i know :) therefor i have "input2"

Comment: @kolboc ("\\s", "") does not work either ...

Comment: Please edit your question to include *exactly*: example inputs, expected results after running the code, a *short, runnable* code, and an explanation of why the results you get from that code is not what you expect. Your question is unclear at it's current state. Remove all unnecessary parts of your story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `next` method of `Scanner` returns the next **token** - with the default delimiters that will be a single word, not the complete line.

Use the `nextLine` method if you want to get the complete line.

Comment: Uhh *facepalm*
That solves both problems. Well, yeah I'm a beginner so never mind and thank you very much :)

There has never been a chance to split on or clean up with whitespaces because there has never been one in my input. Now I got it.

Comment: @FrankDrebin And this is why you need to post [mcve]s with sample inputs and expected outputs. The problem wasn't with the regexes as we can tell after your last edit.

Comment: @user1803551 Thx, will remember for future questions. Now I know that my first one wasn't clear enough.